# Defining views with strange areas

Tags: ios, uiview

My app has a tool bar that runs across the top.  It's a UIView, and I set the space like this:

```
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 50)];
```

I also have another toolbar that runs up and down on the left side.  It's also a UIView, and I set the space like this:

```
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 75, 760)];
```

I would like to combine these two toolbars.  Is it possible to define a view with a non-rectagular area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the view with frame (0,0,1024,810). U can make that view as transparent with backgroundColor set to clearColor.

Comment: Ah, this coupled with insertSubview:atIndex: works.  I was running into the problem that i cannot click anything on my main screen if I made the frame the whole screen.  Thanks Prasad!